# Geofencing using two android app

Tags: java, android, android-geofence

Hi I am new to GeoFencing, Concept of geofencing I understood. I want to implement below scenario in android application:

There are two different android application I want to built: app1(business) and app2(user).

In App1 (Business)
- create geofence area (let's say geofence1)

In App2 (User)
- when user using app2 enters into geofence1(created by business app) user should get notification, so how can I check in app2 either he is entered in business location or not?

What can I implement in app1 and app2?

Answer (score 1):

First off, for geofencing you are going to be using the [Google API](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) to setup call backs for when the user enters the geofenced area. As for communicating the geofence to the user from the business you may want to use something like [Google Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) to allow communication between the two apps. Have the business set a Geofence location, tell Firebase, have the Userapp check firebase and set up the appropriate geofence and callback action.

Sorry if this isnt detailed enough, I am learning myself.

Comment: Hi Charis, Do you know which callback needs to implement at business which will trigger when user enters to business geofence area? I have already implemented GoogleClientAPI to get locations. I have confusion at business app where how app will come to know that user's device enters to business location. There is buzzword location based advertising but how they are targeting end customer? I am also searching if I find anything important then I will share.

Comment: You can use Firebase for that, not sure if its the best solution. But firebase has callbacks that would work like this: User enters GeoFence, adds itself to a list on Firebase of people in GeoFence area. The update to the Firebase triggers an update callback to Business.